# Calling paintComponent method from another paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

is it right to call painComponent method like below:

```
public class CustomComponent{
   private AnotherCustomComponent anotherComponent;
   @override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
        super.paintComponent(arg0);
        anotherComponent.paintComponent(arg0);
        arg0.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 150);
   }
}
```

Comment: Never do that. The painting methods of a component are only responsible for painting itself and will have no knowledge about any other component (other than its parent component).

Comment: @camickr thank you so much for answering, can you also tell me what kind of trouble I will run into if I do that?